# Where can I find the public key to verify the directline.botframework.com conversation JWT token?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, botframework

Following the info from [Azure Bot Service Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) I tried to verify the JWT token using the public keys exposed via OpenId:

- https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

but the key from the directline.botframework.com conversation JWT token is in neither of them, see the error below:

"IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid: '...."

```
        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager =
            new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(openIdMetadataAddress, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConnectConfiguration = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = authorizationDomain,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConnectConfiguration.SigningKeys
        };
        try
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, tokenValidationParameters, out _);
            return true;
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenException)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

JWT token example (generated when you start a directline conversation in bot framework):

```
ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IiwNCiAgImtpZCI6ICJBT08tZXhGd2puR3lDTEJhOTgwVkxOME1tUTgiLA0KICAieDV0IjogIkFPTy1leEZ3am5HeUNMQmE5ODBWTE4wTW1ROCIsDQogICJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIg0KfQ.ew0KICAiYm90IjogImRldi1tYXJpdXNpbXBvLW5lcnRlc3Rib3QwbmVnNC1ib3QiLA0KICAic2l0ZSI6ICJ0RVRMM2ZES3ZGdyIsDQogICJjb252IjogIkZPeXRUdThrTzVRNFVOZmxpS3pSMlgtaCIsDQogICJuYmYiOiAxNTc1MzcxNDYzLA0KICAiZXhwIjogMTU3NTM3NTA2MywNCiAgImlzcyI6ICJodHRwczovL2RpcmVjdGxpbmUuYm90ZnJhbWV3b3JrLmNvbS8iLA0KICAiYXVkIjogImh0dHBzOi8vZGlyZWN0bGluZS5ib3RmcmFtZXdvcmsuY29tLyINCn0.IMKMdlart3nEg6iegVvz5MQ86cp36nLXK1mIT0a7xiOmRLMMlvUjqHA9d2EJUovYAML4RGAapP7BWYgU9CnYtL9dXrJwj_JNacJDov18zUTzbyfzcL8goFJG_PJRjJZbN7ZZZdp1lIis9DbrL56HQBgiBuW4BGhNhgmBauh8SFOIvWfhOYmWoxyfI7Uzkd_5LTVdeL7Lyqi5Ulxzf8UsuDI372US6dA0LZ0BZMCU-M6S9bYFCSBwrvjD5uZOYJ8drCuXnuOl1rxRP_kfMVi-kodWZ84-puo5JYt5QhpptP6vuBYO5-6fW359zJ1csUk-xWFlOH88dh09lpJDbcXgXg
```

[image]

```
using (var client = new DirectLineClient(secretKey))
{
    var conversation = await client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
    var token = conversation.Token;
}
```

Comment: Hey Danut, were you able to verify the token. I've a similar case where the token generated from https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate needs to be validated. I pass it through some middleware for extra modifications. I need to validate it but could not find the open-id config url

Comment: Microsoft does not plan to make the keys public. I used "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/refresh" to validate the token, via http client

Answer (score 4):

**UPD**: I'm not sure what `the key from the directline.botframework.com conversation JWT token` exactly is. If you can provide expired token for me, it should be possible to find out how to validate it.

---

> **Metadata endpoint**:
>
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Your code works fine.

Please check out the steps of the test I've done below:

1. **Create a `Web App Bot`** via Azure Portal.

   Full description here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
2. **Obtain a token**.

   Take `MICROSOFT-APP-ID` and `MICROSOFT-APP-PASSWORD` from the `Configuration` of your `Web App Bot`.

   ```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
   Host: login.microsoftonline.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MICROSOFT-APP-ID&client_secret=MICROSOFT-APP-PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default
   ```
3. Come up with values to validate the token.

   3.1. **Metadata endpoint**

   Constructed from *token endpoint*.

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

   3.2. **Issuer**

   Decoded the token at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and took actual *issuer* from there.

   `https://sts.windows.net/d6d49420-f39b-4df7-a1dc-d59a935871db/`

   3.3. **Audience**

   Same way as for *issuer*.

   `https://api.botframework.com`
4. **Validate the token** and get `ClaimsPrincipal` object decoded from the token.

   ```cs
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       var jwt = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.WWxIinArkAJgVyAUMu6UJvCy9OJ-B2KGxpT-t9wdRF9qlpw00GvXXuL0HCpUEIWC0efA3ETF3bBBJVYjcXoKsC6Up2UWzkAgA2O_TZhPkG5Tkm5MT7f_mIdoEVWoddawjv3ec_EUfSq1B_UrQu-05AHMe0n46kN94yUWbsIAv9z6Q_HSuKO6_kSSyGwbnsAbsT2nWqYyE05BstvZUccQrSvR4UdbugKDEDxAixhVvOrFJiLng3pKeSljXUxWte7ETw59X9EuA4WJPURzW-kWPJ8tGIP2Wz6RVDU-D1eCp-DB3o4PxT-t8UTBMjwUJBFqQo-w1GtQasJwcnUKKkBhgA";
       var claimsPrincipal = await Authenticate(jwt);
   }


   public static async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> Authenticate(string jwt)
   {
       var openIdMetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
       var issuer = "https://sts.windows.net/d6d49420-f39b-4df7-a1dc-d59a935871db/";
       var audience = "https://api.botframework.com";

       var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
           openIdMetadataAddress,
           new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
       var openIdConnectConfiguration = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
       var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           // Updated validation parameters
           ValidIssuer = issuer,
           ValidAudience = audience,
           ValidateLifetime = true,
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConnectConfiguration.SigningKeys
       };

       try
       {
           var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
           var claimsPrincipal = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, tokenValidationParameters, out _);
           return claimsPrincipal;
       }
       catch (SecurityTokenException e)
       {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @DanutRadoaica, could you please elaborate on how to reproduce the issue. How do you obtain this token? I would like to get it myself. It looks like having token itself is not enough to answer your question. There is more info needed.

Comment: @DanutRadoaica, why do you think you need to validate this token at all? `The Direct Line channel is also convenient because it handles bot authentication for us.` https://books.google.nl/books?id=JYxlDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA410&ots=AZjqUhKesl&dq=iss%20https%3A%2F%2Fdirectline.botframework.com%2F&pg=PA409#v=onepage&q=The%20Direct%20Line%20channel%20is%20also%20cenvenient&f=false

Comment: To avoid to generate a new token, I want to use (and validate) the directline conversation JWT token in my own API (that adds some extra functionalities alogside bot framework). The JS web chat should have only one JWT token (so I hope to use the one from bot framework)

Comment: I've updated the question with the new required info